# Какой тип универсальной коллекции в каком случае использовать?

Tags: c#, .net, коллекции

Пространство имен [`System.Collection.Generic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.collections.generic.aspx) содержит *несколько* интерфейсов для работы с универсальными коллекциями.

Наиболее часто мне попадаются следующие интерфейсы:

- `IEnumerable<T>`
- `ICollection<T>`
- `IList<T>`

Хотелось бы узнать, в каких случая рекомендуется использовать тот или иной тип, какие плюсы и минусы использования их по соотношению к друг другу.

Comment: ICollection и производный IList -- данные находятся в памяти. IEnumerable -- данные подгружаются по мере надобности.

Comment: хотя interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>

Comment: @Stack хотелось бы более развернуто

Comment: По-моему всё просто. Члены интерфейсов красноречиво говорят сами за себя. Используйте `IEnumerable<T>`, если вам нужно только перечисление (`foreach`). Если требуются дополнительно `Count`, `Contains` и т.п. то `ICollection<T>`. Если нужен доступ по индексу элемента, то `IList<T>`.

Comment: Вам что-то не ясно из документации?

Comment: @Bald56rus _"хотелось бы более развернуто"_ -- см. ниже мой ответ. текста в нем мало, т.к. их хватает в msdn, но есть примеры на с#.

Comment: @Stack спасибо.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Это семантически разные коллекции, каждая из них добавляет более строгие ограничения, но дает новые возможности:

`IEnumerable<T>` - это, строго говоря, не коллекция. Это просто последовательность, которую можно перебрать по одному элементу. *Нельзя*, например, рассчитывать на то, что

- ее можно перебрать дважды
- ее вообще можно перебрать до конца

`ICollection<T>` - это полноценная коллекция. У нее есть конечное количество элементов, элементы в нее можно добавлять. Имея элемент, можно проверить на существование его в коллекции. И, естественно, коллекцию можно очистить.

`IList<T>` - это коллекция, элементы в которой пронумерованы.

Соответственно, применять нужно то, что позволяют ограничения в каждом конкретном случае. Например:

- Последовательность Фибоначчи - это `IEnumerable<int>` - ее можно перебрать. Но это не `ICollection<T>` - в ней нельзя пересчитать элементы, и в нее нельзя добавить новый элемент. И ее точно нельзя "очистить" :)
- Множество - `HashSet<T>` - это `ICollection<T>`, количество элементов в нем известно, можно добавить новый элемент, можно проверить на существование элемента. Но элементы в множестве никак не отсортированы и не пронумерованы. Соответственно, это не `List<T>`. Аналогично - `Dictionary<Key, Value>` - `ICollection<>`, но не `IList<>`

Решение "что использовать" обычно принимается в двух случаях:

- При реализации собственной коллекции - и тогда стоит просто выбирать тот интерфейс, под ограничения которого ваша коллекция попадает.
- При возврате значения их свойства или метода. Например, внутри у вас есть `List<T>`. Возвращать ли его как `IList<T>`, или как `IEnumerable<T>` - опять же, зависит от контекста. Если подразумевается возврат именно коллекции, но ваш класс не должен реагировать на ее модификацию - то можно вернуть `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`. Если вызывающему достаточно последовательности - ограничьтесь `IEnumerable<T>`. Возвращать внутренний `List<T>` или `T[]`, в зависимости от контекста, может быть небезопасно - вызывающий код сможет напрямую поменять внутренний список вашего класса и поломать вам всю инкапсуляцию.

Сама по себе тема подробно раскрыта в официальном [Framework Design Guidelines - Guidelines for Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо за фиксы :)

Comment: Обращааайся :-D

Comment: Точно сказано про `IEnumerable`. В действительности, нет никакой гарантии, что коллекцию можно будет перебрать несколько раз. Никогда об этом не задумывался

Answer (score 10):

В большинстве случаев достаточно передать или вернуть `IEnumerable<T>`, потому что обычно вызываемый или вызывающий код просто итерируется по коллекции. Об остальных типах коллекций стоит задумываться тогда, когда в этом реально есть необходимость.

Плюсом этого интерфейса является возможность вернуть бесконечные последовательности. Правда не всякий вызывающий код предполагает подобное, поэтому применение возможности не такое широкое.

Из минусов стоит отметить, что по этому интерфейсу не всегда ясно, что за ним скрывается. В результате, чтобы избежать двойной итерации (например, для проверки размера перед итерацией), часто добавляют вызов `ToList()`, даже если за интерфесом список и скрывается, в результате в памяти возникает лишний список. (Эта проблема решается с помощью метода типа `AsList()`, который смотрит реализуемые интерфейсы.)

`ICollection<T>` подразумевает коллекцию, то есть хранилище, в которое можно добавлять и из которого можно удалять элементы. `IList<T>` добавляет понятие индекса элемента. Оба имеют свойство `Count`, то есть необходимость в вызове `ToList()` пропадает.

И не стоит забывать про `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` и `IReadOnlyList<T>`. Если предполагается, что вызывающий код не будет изменять коллекции, то имеет смысл возвращать коллекции только для чтения.

Что точно не надо делать в публичных интерфейсах — это возвращать конкретные коллекции, особенно `List<T>` или `T[]`. Это ограничит ваши возможности изменять реализацию без поломки обратной совместимости в будущем: список и массив не предполагают расширения, в отличие от базового класса `Collection<T>`. (В старом коде .NET много где допущена эта ошибка.)

Если вы работаете с внутренней реализацией, а не с публичным интерфейсом, то обычно нет смысла менять тип переменных, возвращаемых типов и типов аргументов на интерфейсы: вы потеряете время на преобразованиях, а оптимизации того же `List<T>` станут недоступными при вызове методов через интерфейс.

Answer (score 6):

Для работы с коллекциями часто используют List -- если требуется чтобы у получателя коллекции была возможность изменения коллекции.

```
public IList<int> GetList() {
    return new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
}
var lst = GetList();
lst.Add(4);
```

---

Если уже есть коллекция, и ее надо вернуть как readonly:

```
private List<int> _List = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3};
public IList<int> GetReadOnlyList() {
    return _List.AsReadOnly();   // создает обертку
}
```

---

Если значения надо содавать по-запросу

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetValues() {
    var i = 0;
    while (true)
        yield return i++;
}
var values = GetValues().Take(10);
foreach(var v in values) 
  Console.WriteLine(v);
```

---

Если в коллекции находятся объекты, у которых меняются значения свойств, и надо сообщать об этих изменениях, например, для обновления UI.
В такой ситуации используют BindingList

```
 public IList<Data> GetBindingList() {
    var bl = new BindingList<Data>();
    // добавляем объекты в коллекцию
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        bl.Add(new Data() { Id = i, Value = DateTime.Now.Millisecond });
    // по таймеру меняем значения свойств объектов в коллекции
    var r = new Random();
    new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = 500, Enabled = true }
        .Tick += (s, e) => { 
            var i = r.Next(0, bl.Count - 1);
            bl[i].Value = DateTime.Now.Millisecond; };
    return bl;
}
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    // требуется для уведомления о изменении значения свойств.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate {};
    public int Id { get; internal set; }
    public long Value {
        get { return _Value; }
        internal set {
            if (_Value != value) {
                _Value = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
            }}}
    long _Value = 0;
}
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var f = new Form();
    var t = new Test();
    var g = new DataGridView() { 
              Parent = f, 
              Dock = DockStyle.Fill, 
              DataSource = t.GetBindingList() };
    f.ShowDialog();
}
```

---

Если не надо отслеживать изменение свойст у объектов, но требуется отслеживать изменение колличества объектов в коллекции, то вместо BindingList можно использовать ObservableCollection.

Comment: А не могли бы вы рассказать подробнее, когда стоит использовать `BindingList`? Мне он ни разу не попадался за всю практику.

Comment: @VladD _"рассказать подробнее, когда стоит использовать BindingList"_ -- с рассказать подробнее - сложно. дислексия. а если кратко: то BindingList привязывается к INotifyPropertyChanged отлавливает событие PropertyChanged и уведомляет UI о изменении коллекции. попробуйте запустить код из ответа в WinForms. еще пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/474676/6)

Comment: @VladD _"Мне он ни разу не попадался за всю практику"_ -- не знаю почему, но вместо него что только не придумывают. создают свое, что-то вроде TrulyObservableCollection

Comment: Хм. Я всю жизнь использовал в WPF `ObservableCollection<VM>` для списка, а элементы списка привязывал через `Binding`, и всё работало. Или это специфика WinForms?

Comment: @VladD _"это специфика WinForms?"_ -- нет. уведомления бывают нужны не только для работы с UI, а для взаимодействия в ComponentModel

Comment: Ну это да, но на мой вкус в правильной архитектуре _контейнеру_ не нужно и даже вредно знать о том, что внутренности _элемента_ в контейнере изменились. Если кто-то хочет следить за внутренним объектом, он обычно следит за одним выбранным объектом, и ему не нужна вся коллекция.

Comment: Например, вот так: http://pastebin.com/w1knxZra. `ItemsControl` следит за коллекцией, и ему всё равно, что там меняется внутри ChildVM'ов. А `DataTemplate`-ы следит за каждым отдельным ChildVM'ом, и их не интересует вся коллекция. То есть необходимости в BindingList нету. А в каком случае для WPF такая необходимость есть?

Comment: @VladD в WPF отслеживанием значений свойств занимается Binding. в WPF использовать BindingList не обязательно. просто представьте, что нет WPF, вообще нет, но есть модель данных, и надо уведомлять подписчиков об изменении свойств элементов коллекции.

Comment: Ага, теперь понял. Хотя мне вроде такое не было нужно даже в бекэнде. Но юзкейс валидный, да.

Comment: @VladD в .net есть еще один способ уведомления об изменении значения свойства. сейчас точно не скажу. надо смотреть старый код.

Answer (score 5):

`IList<T>` наследует `ICollection<T>` который в свою очередь наследует `IEnumerable<T>`

`IEnumerable<T>` -содержит всего 1 метод: `new IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();`
Это базовый интерфейс для коллекций дженериков которые вам хотелось бы обрабатывать с помощью `foreach` (или каким либо другим образом использовать `GetEnumerator()`) Подробнее [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

`ICollection<T>` и `IList<T>` расширяют инструментарий для работы с коллекциями(подробнее о содержании можно глянуть тут: ([`ICollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/92t2ye13%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),[`IList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) или [тут](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) (использовать поиск)

Другими словами выбор конкретного интерфейса зависит от того, какие операции с коллекцией вам хотелось бы использовать. И единственная рекомендация которая тут может быть: руководствоваться здравым смыслом и учитывать задачи в которых используются объекты реализующие данные интерфейсы

А вот то где хранятся данные и как с ними осуществляется работа это уже дело класса реализующего интерфейс. И от самого интерфейса тут ничего не зависит. Класс реализующий данные интерфейсы, строго говоря, может реализовать их совсем непредсказуемым для вас образом и, например, тот же `GetEnumerator()` может возвращать вам `null` даже если коллекция не пустая или, например, генерировать исключение....

Answer (score 5):

В .NET 4.0 появились ещё два полезных интерфейса: `IReadOnlyCollection` и `IReadOnlyList` (оба пока недоступны в portable-сборках).

Как понять, на каком интерфейсе остановиться? По тому, какие сценарии предполагаются для входных и выходных данных.

`IEnumerable` в действительности является реализацией паттерна `Iterator`, предоставляет минимальный интерфейс и подходит в подавляющем большинстве случаев. Однако любимый решарпер всё время его ругает, потому что за итератором может скрываться код, который читает код из сети, с диска, с коммуникационного порта.

Так что если за интерфейсом скрывается `List` или `Array` используйте `IReadOnlyCollection`. Поскольку у интерфейса есть свойство `Count`, предполагается, что все данные доступны для повторных итераций.

Довольно трудно определить разницу между `IReadOnlyCollection` и `IReadOnlyList`. Второй интерфейс нужен в случаях, когда порядок элеметов в коллекции важен для вызывающей стороны. Например, если коллекция реализует принципы FIFO или LIFO (очередь и стек соответственно), то это всё-таки list. Если порядок определяется вызываемой стороной (хеш-таблица, сортированной список), тогда речь идёт о collection.

Использование `ICollection` и `IList` нужно только в тех случаях, когда вы хотите дать доступ не только по чтению, но и по записи.