# Событие в списке объектов

Tags: c#

Есть класс `MyClass`, в котором есть событие на изменения свойства (например, через  `INotifyPropertyChanged`). В другом классе `MyMainClass` создается список таких объектов `public List<MyClass> Data { get; set; }`. Как обработать событие, когда в списке объектов изменилось значение свойства? Добавился/удалился элемент в/список не интересует.

Comment: нужно реагировать на изменение свойства конкретного объекта?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого придется реализовать собственную коллекцию, которая будет следить за добавляемыми и удаляемыми элементами. Если вам понадобятся события удаления/добавления элемента, отнаследуйте этот класс от `ObservableCollection<T>`.

```
// Не является потокобезопасной
public sealed class ItemObservableCollection<T> : Collection<T>
    where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler ItemPropertyChanged;

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
        item.PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged;
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        var item = this[index];
        base.RemoveItem(index);
        item.PropertyChanged -= item_PropertyChanged;
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
    {
        var oldItem = this[index];
        base.SetItem(index, item);
        oldItem.PropertyChanged -= item_PropertyChanged;
        item.PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged;
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged -= item_PropertyChanged;
        }
        base.ClearItems();
    }

    private void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ItemPropertyChanged != null)
        {
            ItemPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Кажется, можно использовать `BindingList`: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477539

Comment: @VladD я уже и забыл про такую штуку :). Правда работа с ней чуть более неуклюжа -- там общее событие и на изменение элементов, и на изменение коллекции.

Comment: Я этим контейнером вообще ни разу не пользовался: в WPF без него всё прекрасно работает, достаточно `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, вам подойдёт `BindingList<T>` вместо `List<T>`: он умеет слать нотификации не только об изменении списка, но и об изменении *элементов* списка.

```
var l = new BindingList<MyClass>();
l.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
// кажется, нужно ещё
((IRaiseItemChangedEvents)l).RaisesItemChangedEvents = true;

l.ListChanged += (o, args) =>
    {
         if (args.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemChanged)
            // изменился элемент с индексом e.NewIndex
    };
```