# IEnumerable или IList что лучше всего использовать?

Tags: c#

прочитав несколько статей я понял что например когда данные тащим из бд то лучше использовать IEnumerable а в других случаях IList

Comment: А ведь еще есть `ICollection` (=

Comment: `когда данные тащим из бд то лучше использовать IEnumerable` - `IQueryable` же

Comment: [Ассоциация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/477488/193999)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IEnumerable` - это просто некое множество, которое можно перебрать один за другим. `IList` же - более конкретный интерфейс, подразумевающий некий список элементов (имеющий фиксированный порядок) и предоставляющий возможность доступа к любому элементу по индексу. Если эти дополнительные возможности `IList` не требуются, то стоит выбрать более абстрактный тип - `IEnumerable`. Правило универсально: во внешнем API лучше стараться использовать наиболее универсальный тип из походящих.

И да, когда формируется запрос через ORM, вроде EF, то лучше до окончания построения запроса пользоваться `IQueriable`, чтобы сократить объем данных, вытягиваемых в память их базы.